# Rust вернуть socket из функции подключения

Tags: websocket, rust

Всех приветствую.
Вынес код для подключения к бирже в отдельный модуль, правда не могу разобраться какой тип прописать для возвращаемых данных, вернуть нужно переменную **socket**. Редактор подсказывает следующий вариант:

```
pub fn binance() -> WebSocket<Stream<TcpStream, rustls::stream::StreamOwned<rustls::client::ClientSession, TcpStream>>>
```

Однако на такую запись ругается что модуль **stream** приватный, а **WebSocket** он найти не может.

Код модуля **ConnectExchange.rs**:

```
use log::info;
use log4rs;
use tungstenite::connect;
use url::Url;

pub fn binance() {
    log4rs::init_file("log4rs.yaml", Default::default()).unwrap();

    let url_connect = "wss://fstream.binance.com";
    let symbol = "btcusdt";
    let key_api = "forceOrder";
    let binance_api_url = format!("{}/ws/{}@{}", url_connect, symbol, key_api);

    let (mut socket, response) =
        connect(Url::parse(&binance_api_url).unwrap()).expect("Can`t connect to Binance.");

    info!(target: "special","Connected to Binance stream.");
    info!(target: "special","HTTP status code: {}", response.status());
    info!(target: "special", "Response headers:");

    for (ref header, ref header_value) in response.headers() {
        info!(target: "special","- {}: {:?}", header, header_value);
    }

    return socket;
}
```

Код **main.rs**

```
mod ConnectExchange;

use colored::Colorize;
use std::process::Command;
use ConnectExchange::binance;

struct CoinEvent {
    coin: String,
    side: String,
    price: String,
    volume: String,
    time: String,
}

fn main() {
    Command::new("clear")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Not use clear command.");
    binance();

    let side = ["SHORT", "LONG"];

    loop {
        let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message...");

        if let tungstenite::Message::Text(msg) = msg {
            let parsed: serde_json::Value =
                serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Unable to parse msg...");

            let ts: i64 = parsed["o"]["T"].to_string().parse::<i64>().unwrap() / 1000;

            let nt = NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(ts, 0);
            let dt: DateTime<Utc> = DateTime::from_utc(nt, Utc);
            let res = dt.format("%H:%M %m.%d");

            let info = CoinEvent {
                coin: parsed["o"]["s"]
                    .to_string()
                    .replace("\"", "")
                    .replace("USDT", ""),
                side: parsed["o"]["S"].to_string().replace("\"", ""),
                price: parsed["o"]["p"].to_string().replace("\"", ""),
                volume: parsed["o"]["q"].to_string().replace("\"", ""),
                time: res.to_string().replace("\"", ""),
            };

            if info.side == "BUY" {
                println!(
                    "{} : {} : {} : {} : {}",
                    info.coin.blue().bold(),
                    side[0].blue().bold(),
                    info.price.blue().bold(),
                    info.volume.blue().bold(),
                    info.time.blue().bold()
                );
            } else if info.side == "SELL" {
                println!(
                    "{} : {}  : {} : {} : {}",
                    info.coin.red().bold(),
                    side[1].red().bold(),
                    info.price.red().bold(),
                    info.volume.red().bold(),
                    info.time.red().bold()
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее, благодарен!

Comment: Правильно подсказывает. Просто нужно ещё в начала написать `use tungstenite::WebSocket;`. А на счёт модуля попробуйте написать `pub mod stream;`, по вашему кусочку не понятно в чём проблема.

Comment: @vessd Добавил сюда код main файла, дело в том, что когда я вписываю то что советует редактор, начинается чехарда, потом он просит подключить rustls::ClientSession, std::net::TcpStream, и так по кругу...

Answer (score 0):

Пример

connect_exchange.rs

```
use std::net::TcpStream;

use url::Url;
use tungstenite::{connect, stream::MaybeTlsStream, WebSocket};

pub fn binance() -> WebSocket<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>> {
    let url_connect = "wss://fstream.binance.com";
    let symbol = "btcusdt";
    let key_api = "forceOrder";
    let binance_api_url = format!("{}/ws/{}@{}", url_connect, symbol, key_api);

    let (socket, response) =
        connect(Url::parse(&binance_api_url).unwrap()).expect("Can`t connect to Binance.");

    socket
}
```

main.rs

```
mod connect_exchange;

use connect_exchange::binance;

fn main() {
    let mut socket = binance();

    loop {
        let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message...");

        if let tungstenite::Message::Text(msg) = msg {
            let parsed: serde_json::Value =
                serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Unable to parse msg...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пишет `unresolved import tungstenite::stream::MaybeTlsStream no MaybeTlsStream in stream`, нет такого модуля ((

Comment: @CodeMan А какие-нибудь фитчи указаны для `tungstenite` в `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: Только это прописано tungstenite = { version="0.14.0", features = ["rustls-tls"]}

Comment: А почему версия старая? Там сейчас 0.17 уже есть. Для вашей версии `use tungstenite::{client::AutoStream, connect, WebSocket};` и `WebSocket<AutoStream>`.
А ответ дан для актуальной